# Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider Ionic Framework/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Following the [local storage tutorial on the Ionic blog](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/), I'm trying to set/get a localStorage value when my Ionic app runs but I get the error message:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $localstorageProvider <- $localstorage
```

My app.js code:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $localstorage) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    $localstorage.set('name', 'Ian');
    console.log($localstorage.get('name'));
  });
})
```

And services.js:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    set: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    },
    get: function(key, defaultValue) {
      return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    }
  }
}]);
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.

**EDIT**:  If I change my app.js code to the following, it works as expected:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $localstorage) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    window.localStorage.setItem('name', 'Ian');
    console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('name'));

  });
})
```

Comment: I see this dependency on the module definition angular.module('ionic.utils', [])
are you missing ionic.utils?

Comment: ionic.utils is what they named the service but I've placed their code inside starter.services instead.

Comment: Did you add dependency to `services.js` in your html file?

Comment: Yeah, I've got `<script src="js/services.js"></script>` in `index.html`.

Comment: This might help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/mVbmrvZHXEQ i.e, do you have an ngStorage dependency?

Comment: I found that during my search, but I'm using Ionic/Cordova/PhoneGap implementation of localStorage: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circling back to this, I was able to fix it by injecting $window:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $window ) {
```

Then I was able to get/set by using:

```
$window.localStorage.setItem( 'name', 'Ian' );
$window.localStorage.getItem( 'name' ); // Ian
```

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem with the Ionic tutorial implementation:
http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/

It worked when I removed the $ sign in front of localstorage.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, localstorage)
```

Comment: yeah it works but why on earth works ? :) I've tried to put the snippet in a simple angular app (using $localstorage) and it works with no trouble so .....

Comment: PS it works changing name like myStorage or whatever but not only removed the $ in front of localstorage

Comment: Because it is not inbuilt. That is a custom factory name. Which in your case, you have written as .factory('localstorage', ['$window', function($window) { and in the tutorial it is #localstorage